# Benchmarking each line in Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, process, benchmarking

Is there a tool that I could use to get the benchmark of my python program. I want to see how long each line takes to process rather than to use the `%timeit` for each line is there another library that could help me achieve this?

Code:

```
%%time
from numpy import random
Appending_list = []
Values = random.randint(100, size=(100000))
Number_array = random.randint(100, size=(1000))
for n in range(len(Values)):
    result = np.sum(Number_array) + Values[n] * len(Number_array)
    Appending_list.append(result)
```

[image]

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html

Answer (score 3):

you can use [PySnooper](https://github.com/cool-RR/PySnooper) library:

you've to wrap your code in a function or a class. then decorate that function or class with `@pysnooper.snoop()` 
set `relative_time=True` for your requirement.

here's an example:

```
import pysnooper

@pysnooper.snoop(relative_time=True)
def number_to_bits(number):
    if number:
        bits = []
        while number:
            number, remainder = divmod(number, 2)
            bits.insert(0, remainder)
        return bits
    else:
        return [0]
```

after calling the function: `number_to_bits(10)`

output :

```
Source path:... <ipython-input-28-59cb3f746130>
Starting var:.. number = 10
00:00:00.000002 call         4 def number_to_bits(number):
00:00:00.000752 line         5     if number:
00:00:00.000884 line         6         bits = []
New var:....... bits = []
00:00:00.000956 line         7         while number:
00:00:00.001070 line         8             number, remainder = divmod(number, 2)
Modified var:.. number = 5
New var:....... remainder = 0
00:00:00.001146 line         9             bits.insert(0, remainder)
Modified var:.. bits = [0]
00:00:00.001299 line         7         while number:
00:00:00.001395 line         8             number, remainder = divmod(number, 2)
Modified var:.. number = 2
Modified var:.. remainder = 1
00:00:00.001468 line         9             bits.insert(0, remainder)
Modified var:.. bits = [1, 0]
00:00:00.001571 line         7         while number:
00:00:00.001653 line         8             number, remainder = divmod(number, 2)
Modified var:.. number = 1
Modified var:.. remainder = 0
00:00:00.001715 line         9             bits.insert(0, remainder)
Modified var:.. bits = [0, 1, 0]
00:00:00.001842 line         7         while number:
00:00:00.001953 line         8             number, remainder = divmod(number, 2)
Modified var:.. number = 0
Modified var:.. remainder = 1
00:00:00.002030 line         9             bits.insert(0, remainder)
Modified var:.. bits = [1, 0, 1, 0]
00:00:00.002155 line         7         while number:
00:00:00.002281 line        10         return bits
00:00:00.002355 return      10         return bits
Return value:.. [1, 0, 1, 0]
Elapsed time: 00:00:00.002523
[1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

While there are profiling tools, I think a smart use of `timeit` often is better.

For example.  The whole loop (minus the import)

```
In [15]: %%timeit
    ...: Appending_list = []
    ...: Values = np.random.randint(100, size=(100000))
    ...: Number_array = np.random.randint(100, size=(1000))
    ...: for n in range(len(Values)):
    ...:     result = np.sum(Number_array) + Values[n] * len(Number_array)
    ...:     Appending_list.append(result)
    ...:
```

1.19 s ± 937 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

But the `random` step is minor

```
In [16]: %timeit Values = np.random.randint(100, size=(100000))
    ...: 
1.24 ms ± 404 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [18]: %%timeit Values = np.random.randint(100, size=(100000)); Number_array = np.random.randint(100, si
    ...: ze=(1000))
    ...: Appending_list = []
    ...: for n in range(len(Values)):
    ...:     result = np.sum(Number_array) + Values[n] * len(Number_array)
    ...:     Appending_list.append(result)
    ...: 
    ...: 
1.19 s ± 2.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

But apart from the append, that loop is just doing the sum line 100000 times.  Lets time that alone:

```
In [19]: timeit (np.sum(Number_array)+Values*Number_array.shape[0])
313 µs ± 4.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

But wait, why do the `sum` 100000 times; do it just once

```
In [20]: %%timeit Values = np.random.randint(100, size=(100000)); Number_array = np.random.randint(100, si
    ...: ze=(1000))
    ...: Appending_list = []
    ...: s = np.sum(Number_array)
    ...: for n in range(len(Values)):
    ...:     result = s + Values[n] * len(Number_array)
    ...:     Appending_list.append(result)
    ...: 

53.3 ms ± 57.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Better yet, do the `Values` multiply all at once, rather than in a loop:

```
In [21]: timeit np.sum(Number_array) + Values * Number_array.shape[0]
329 µs ± 10.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

I also verified that the [21] calculation does the same thing.